# jQuery: Remove Text from HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove "or" from this HTML code:

```
<div>
  <a href="https://store-b2aus7wd.mybigcommerce.com/account.php">Account</a>
  <a href='https://store-b2aus7wd.mybigcommerce.com/login.php' onclick=''>Sign in</a> 
 or
  <a href='https://store-b2aus7wd.mybigcommerce.com/login.php?action=create_account' onclick=''>Create an account</a>
</div>
```

using this code:

```
$("div").html().replace(/\or/g,"");
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: What happens if one of the URLs contains the text "or" it it somewhere?

Comment: `\o` is unnecessary and might even cause errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of working with the html as a string, it might be better to do this by working with the DOM objects:

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) == 'or';
}).remove();
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm4pC/. It looks like the `.remove()` has an odd effect on the spacing. Using `.replaceWith('\n')` or `.replaceWith(' ')` instead may work better depending on your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/kdYQP/

Answer (score 2):

`$("div").html()` returns the current html of the div as a string.  Which you then manipulate.  As a string.  You need to assign it back:

```
$("div").html( $("div").html().replace(/\or/g,"") );
```

That said, are you sure you want to do it that way with a regexp?  If the characters "or" appear in one of the urls they get removed too.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do?  remove exactly that text? or remove everything not a link? or what?

Comment: Maybe fix up the regex to require spaces. `/\sor\s/`, and remove the global flag.

Comment: I just want to remove that exact text.

Comment: Maybe `replace(/>(\s*)\or(\s*)</g,">$1$2<")` as a regexp.  matches a close tag followed by space then or then space then an open tag but puts the open/close and the spaces back as part of the replacement. But if you are happy with your regexp then you just need to assign it back as described in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this in case you can remove all the text (as of now it's a little unclear) and don't feel like using a regex statement:

```
$("div").html($("div a"));
```

This will change the HTML of the `div` to only include the `a` elements, essentially removing all the text from the HTML. In this case, the only text there is `or`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/r974V/)

Comment: I thought of that (or `$('div').html( $('div').children() )`) but the problem is you loose the whitespace between the links.